# Is the `in` keyword useful besides in a `for` loop?

Tags: javascript

In JS. Can you name another instance where the `in` reserved keyword is useful/practical besides in a `for` loop *(i.e `for (a in b) [...]`)*

Comment: You can use it to check if a property exists in an object's prototype chain.

Answer (score 3):

It's useful in `if`:

```
if (key in object) {
    ...
}
```

This will execute the code if `key` is a property name (potentially inherited from a prorotype) in `object`.